# add str to start of each row value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

`df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [1, 34, 34, 104 , 6542, 6542 ,  48383]})`

I want to append a `str` before each row`s value.

The `str` is `ZZ00000`

The catch is that the row data must always = 7 characters in total

so the desired output will be

```
df =    num_legs
0   ZZ00001
1   ZZ00034
2   ZZ00034
3   ZZ00104
4   ZZ06542
5   ZZ06542
6   ZZ48383
```

As the column is of type `int` I was thinking of changing to a `str` type and then possibly using regex and some `str` manipulation to achieve my desired outcome..

Is there a more streamlined way possibly using a function with `pandas`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
df['num_legs'] = "ZZ" + df['num_legs'].astype(str).str.rjust(5, "0")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use string concatenation here:

```py
df["num_legs"] = 'ZZ' + ('00000' + str(df["num_legs"]))[-5:]
```

The idea here is that, given a `num_legs` integer value of say `6542`, we first form the following string:

```
000006542
```

Then we retain the right 5 characters, leaving `06542`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also pad using the following:

```
'ZZ' + df['num_legs'].astype(str).str.pad(width=5, side='left', fillchar='0')
```

Here you pad your current number (converted to string) on the left with zeros up to a width of 5 and conctatenate that to your 'ZZ' string.

Answer (score 2):

Use pythons `.zfill()`

```
df['num_legs']='zz'+df['num_legs'].astype(str).str.zfill(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -  using a regex, and a for loop: for strings, for loops are more efficient, usually, than pandas String methods :

```
    import re

variable = "ZZ00000"

df["new_val"] = [re.sub("\d" + f"{{{len(num)}}}$", num, variable) 
                for num in df.num_legs.astype(str)]
df

  num_legs  new_val
0   1       ZZ00001
1   34      ZZ00034
2   34      ZZ00034
3   104     ZZ00104
4   6542    ZZ06542
5   6542    ZZ06542
6   48383   ZZ48383
```

Answer (score -1):

```
out = []
for nl in df["num_legs"]:    
    out.append(f'ZZ{nl:05d}')
```

The rest is up to your output manipulation

Comment: Using a python `for` loop to iterate over elements in a Pandas Series is something you would want to avoid where possible. Pandas comes with methods to achieve the required result without the need of the for loop.